# How to move to trash and don't mark as delete in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

I have just finished setting up mu4e in emacs with spacemacs.

When I delete a message, it moves to trash folder and is marked as deleted. So, each time it sync. I can't see anything in the trace folder.

There is a way to make a keybinding that does it. But is there a way to modify the behaviour of the delete key?

Comment: @phils sorry, its trash.

Comment: Mu4e already has a move command, so you could just use that -- instead of deleting things, just move them to the trash.